# Get symbol by address (symbolicating binary, iOS build)

Tags: ios, xcode, armv7, symbolicate, object-address

I have snapshot of Allocations Instrument with address of interesting symbol:

[image: Here is screenshot]

And I want to know, where this address is in code. I have corresponding dSYM file. I tried to use `atosym` command-line tool but it gives me wrong symbols (not related to my app).

How to get it?

PS: The binary was built by XCode 4.3.2, code language is C++, armv7 architecture, release build configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dwarfdump` does what I need:

```
dwarfdump --arch armv7 myApp.dSYM --lookup 0xaabbccdd
```